# intento crear un entorno virtual en python pero me sale error cuando lo voy a arrancar

Tags: python, django

eso es lo que me sale cuando intento correr el programa pero desde el cmd si corre bien

```
PyDev console: starting
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Django 3.2.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pycharm\django_manage_shell.py", line 31, in run
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Users\luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 206, in run_module
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Users\luigi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 141, in _get_module_details
    raise error("No module named %s" % mod_name)
ImportError: No module named manage
```

Comment: te recomiendo que uses el entorno virtual de Python por defecto `venv`. También seria bueno que coloques lo que tienes en tu archivo `runpy.py`

Answer (score 0):

Lo más recomendable es hacer el entorno virtual antes de crear el proyecto de Django, ya que dentro del entorno virtual puedes elegir que versión de Django usarás durante todo el desarrollo para ello primero ejecutar el siguiente comando dentro de la carpeta donde crearas tu proyecto:

```
virtualenv -p python3
```

Una vez hecho esto ejecutar:

```
source bin/activate
```

Para entrar al entorno virtual. Para salir de este solamente ejecutar: `deactivate`

Dentro del entorno virtual ahora si instalas la versión de Django que quieras con:

```
pip install django==2.0.7
```

Puedes poner la versión que más se te acomode a usar. Ahora si creas tu proyecto Django y ejecutas `python manage.py runserver` para ver que todo funcionó de manera correcta.